# ListView is giving me a blank page

Tags: android, android-listview

Im trying to get ListView to display a list of accounts but its returning a blank page. Im not getting any error messages either. I have looked around for similar issues but none of the solution is a fix to this problem. Grateful if someone could help.

FILE > ListActivity.java

```
public class ListeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste);

        Guichet guichet = new Guichet();
        ArrayList<Epargne> epargneList = new ArrayList<Epargne>(guichet.listEpargne);
        
        EpargneAdapter adapter = new EpargneAdapter(ListeActivity.this, R.layout.liste_comptes, epargneList);
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.maListe);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

FILE > EpargneAdapter.java

```
    private ArrayList<Epargne> epargneList;
    private Context context;
    private int viewRes;
    private Resources res;

    public EpargneAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Epargne> versions) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, versions);
        this.epargneList = versions;
        this.context = context;
        this.viewRes = textViewResourceId;
        this.res = context.getResources();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.
                    LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(viewRes, parent, false);
        }
        final Epargne epargne = epargneList.get(position);

        if (epargne != null) {
            final TextView numero = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numeroCompte);
            final TextView solde = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.soldeCompte);

            String numeroC = res.getString(R.string.numero) + " " + epargne.getNumeroCompte();
            numero.setText(numeroC);
            String SoldeC =res.getString(R.string.solde) + " " + epargne.getSoldeCompte();
            solde.setText(SoldeC);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

FILE > activity_liste.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListeActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/maListe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dp"
        />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

FILE > liste_Compte.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/numeroCompte"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/soldeCompte"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

FILE > Guichet.java

```
public class Guichet extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Epargne> listEpargne = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        setTitle("Guichet automatique ATM");

        initListEpargne(listEpargne);
    }


    public void initListEpargne(ArrayList<Epargne> listEpargne) {
        Epargne epargne1 = new Epargne();
        epargne1.setNumeroCompte("E0001");
        epargne1.setSoldeCompte(10000);
        listEpargne.add(epargne1);

        Epargne epargne2 = new Epargne();
        epargne2.setNumeroCompte("E0002");
        epargne2.setSoldeCompte(10000);
        listEpargne.add(epargne2);

        Epargne epargne3 = new Epargne();
        epargne3.setNumeroCompte("E0003");
        epargne3.setSoldeCompte(10000);
        listEpargne.add(epargne3);

        Epargne epargne4 = new Epargne();
        epargne4.setNumeroCompte("E0004");
        epargne4.setSoldeCompte(10000);
        listEpargne.add(epargne4);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show how your `Guichet` class looks like? and make sure `guichet.listEpargne` already has data in it.

Comment: check size of `guichet.listEpargne`

Comment: I added the file Guichet.java

Comment: you are right. The size of `guichet.listEpargne` = 0. I fixed it. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the `listEpargne` when you call it.

But lets forget it. You create a class that extends the `AppCompatActivity` and try to create that class with `new` keyword :o.

The classes which extend from the `AppCompatActivity` should create only by intent and than to start.

You can make a class called Guichet who don't extends the `AppCompatActivity` and there provide a method `getData()`. This method will return that list. But don't forgot to initialize and fill that list :).

Comment: Thanks Emanuel. I initiated `listEpargne` and it works fine now.